# How to create child page for parent page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to create child pages for all pages (which do not have child pages). It shoud be one time script/function. I tried to do smth like that

```
$my_post = array(
'post_title'    => 'My post',
'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'post_author'   => 1,
'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

But dont know that to do else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need save_post action, here you can find example

http://pastebin.com/CvryjJCV